# Maximiser CRM Data Migration, UnEncoding Email Text from Binary Image Column

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hex, decode, talend

Hi Firstly I realise this is not a direct programming question as it is more data related so if it needs to go elsewhere fair enough.

I'm trying to extract Email Message text from a Maximizer CRM system for a Migration.
This information appears to reside in the AMGR_Letter_Tbl, however I’m having a few issue decoding it.

The Column in Maximizer CRM’s documentation at database level is described as a “Binary Image”, this appears accurate and for some entries (Documents) in the table casting via MSSQL obtains a readable response (See the bottom 2 rows in my query results).
However for Email Messages there appears to be at least one extra level of encoding or encryption applied.  (See the my UnEncoding attempts below).

I’m hoping some one  will either have encountered this issue before, know from experience with Maximizer CRM what’s needed Or will recognise the next step needed from my un-encoding attempts.

If you do know please describe what un-encoding, casting, other procedures and there required order or application.

I will be fitting this into a bigger Talend migration when I know what decoding is needed so any code examples in Talend OS or  Java would be appreciated.

Cheers Andy

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the column type in the Maximizer DB ?

Comment: This is a proprietary and undocumented Maximizer format. We may be able to help you with this extraction as I have spent a lot of time on the problem. Please contact me directly via www.cabc.co.uk CABC Maximizer Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know I solved this issue and the contents of the table are Microsoft OLE encoded [OLE File format info](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/OLE_Compound_File)
I now have an extraction method that recovers Documents, Emails and Emails attachments stored this way.

The scripts are using a  number of system tools and third party Java library's controlled via Talend.
However I can't give too much away as to create these has taken a significant amount of time and effort.

If you want more info please get in contact directly.

Cheers